# DocumentDB Query documents where Array_Length > 1

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have sets of documents that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Document1",
    "Properties": {
      "Property1": [
        "Value1",
        "Value2",
        "Value3",
      ]
    },
    "Tags": null
  },
  {
    "Name": "Document2",
    "Properties": {
      "Property1": [
        "Value1",
      ]
    },
    "Tags": null
  },
  {
    "Name": "Document3",
    "Properties": {
      "Property1": [
        "Value1",
        "Value2",
      ]
    "Property2": [
        "Value1",
      ]
    },
    "Tags": null
  }
]
```

I need to query for any documents where the the `Property1` array within the Properties node has more that 1 item. In my example above I would expect to only get back `Document1` and `Document3`. I have spent a great deal of time experimenting with the Array_Contains syntax but keep coming up short. Here is what my latest attempt looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM Docs d WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH([d.Properties, 'Property1']) > 1
```

But with my syntax I get back every document.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need a query like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Docs d WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(d.Properties.Property1) > 1
```

Note that DocumentDB's grammar works over hierarchical nested data,  and you can access properties like d.Properties.Property1, d.Properties.Property1[0], etc. like in a programming language.

Comment: Thanks Aravind. This works on properties without spaces in the names, but breaks down on  queries where "Property1" might be spelled "Property 1" - How can I use a string for that variable. So far I've tried: SELECT * FROM Docs d WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(d.Properties.["Property 1"]) > 1

Comment: I figured it out: SELECT * FROM Docs d WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(d.Properties["Property 1"]) > 1

Comment: `SELECT * FROM myItems AS m
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(m.subCollection) > 0`
I don't know why but this query returns an empty response `[]`. There are items with non-empty `subCollection` so I'm expecting to get them.